# change the colname of the R dataframe on matching multiple condition

Tags: r

Can anyone help me with the question. actually I have a dataframe with n rows and m columns, first column of the dataframe have 2 string characters (john, Michaeal) and rest other columns have values 0 or 1. I am trying to name all the column based on the condition if fist column as if name == john and the value in one of the Multiple column is 1, than colname as "John" else "others"

I tried this method

```
names(df) = ifelse(df$name=="John" & rowSums(df[, 2:5800]==1), "John", "Others")
```

df Input

```
name    col1   col2 col3 col4 col5
john    0     1    0     0    0
Micheal 1   0.   0.  0.  0 
john.   0  0.   1.  0  0
```

desired output

```
name   others John. john. others. others
john    0     1    0     0    0
Micheal 1   0.   0.  0.  0 
john.   0  0.   1.  0  0
```

Thanks

Comment: I have made example dataset in original post, sorry I am new here, I dont know to create df here in clear way

Comment: I am getting this error. "Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [22245] must be the same length as the vector [5800]"

Comment: Datasets are usually shared as `dput` so that it is easier to copy. This post can help in creating a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 2):

You can subset only the rows where `name` is `'john'` and take sum of those columns. Find out which column has atleast one 1 and rename them to `'John'` and rest of them to `'Others'`.

```
inds <- which(colSums(df[df$name == 'john', -1]) > 0) + 1
names(df)[inds] <- 'John'
names(df)[setdiff(2:ncol(df), inds)] <- 'Others'
df
#     name Others John John Others Others
#1    john      0    1    0      0      0
#2 Micheal      1    0    0      0      0
#3    john      0    0    1      0      0
```

However, note that it is not advised to have same column names in a dataframe. You can make them unique with `make.unique`

```
names(df) <- make.unique(names(df))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("john", "Micheal", "john"), col1 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L), col2 = c(1, 0, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1), col4 = c(0, 0, 
0), col5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```